# about the react hook useEffect deps array

Tags: react-hooks

```
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        getApiValues();
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
    
        //problem is when enter this page from another, sometimes value1  is 0 ,but actually is not 0 . 

        setApiValues(value1,value2);
    
      }, [value1,value2]);

    
      const getApiValue1= () => {
        const info = {
          corpid:'corpid',     
          userid:'userid'
        };
        fetch(`url`,{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(info)
          })  
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if(json.result === 'succ') {
            ....
            setvalue1(value1);
            setvalue2(value2);
          }
        });
      };
    
     const setApiValues = () => {
      .....
     }
```

the problem is that i get data from getApiValue1  and then 2 setState , sometiems ,not everytime , value1 is set to 0 , actually is not 0 .

when setvalue2(value2) happen , value2 changed , it will trigger useEffect ,why get value1 is 0 ?

and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the values in two separate `setValueX` calls, the Effect may be run for both updates as well. If you want to set both values and only run the Effect once, consider putting them in a single state object and updating them together, eg.

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({ value1: 0, value2: 0 })

// fetch and set values
const fetchValues = async () => {
  //...
  const res = await fetch('something', options)
  const { value1, value2 } = await res.json()
  setValues({ value1, value2 })
}

// run fetch on mount
useEffect(fetchValues, [])
```

Comment: useEffect(() => {

setApiValues(values.value1,values.value2);
},[values])     like this?

Comment: I have no idea what `setApiValues` does. I'd just call `fetchValues` as defined above on first render. I extended the example a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to use useEffect as a way to control the flow of your data, more about this [here](https://youtu.be/HPoC-k7Rxwo). Why don't you just call `setApiValues` instead of `setvalue1` and `setvalue2`?

Comment: setApiValues  is to save the value to Database , value1 and value2 is for UI show .